# value retrieval from the shared preferences not working as expected

Tags: android

I am trying to set the text property of a text view dynamically. But getting the app force closed. what is the problem of my below code ?

```
public class DataStorageActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();

        editor.putInt("myValue", 7);

        editor.commit();

        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

       int value=settings.getInt("myValue", 0);

        tv.setText(value);

    }
}
```

**Edit**

According to @agamov I have fixed the above issue. But I have encountered the same problem with the below code even after passing a string type to the setText Method. What's the problem here ?

```
public class InternalStorageActivity extends Activity {

    public String fileName="HelloFile";

    public TextView textview;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        String helloString="Hello";
        byte[] b = null;

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos=openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);

            fos.write(helloString.getBytes());

            fos.close();

            FileInputStream fis=openFileInput(fileName);
            fis.read(b);
            String input=b.toString();

            textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

            textview.setText(input);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your log cat?

Comment: @Tamil LogCat shows Fatal Exception at main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing int to TextView.
This should fix your bug:

```
int value=settings.getInt("myValue", 0);
tv.setText("" + value);
```

Comment: can u please look into my edit portion of the question and help me resolve it ?

Comment: check your persmissions in AndroidManifest.xml. Do you have permissions to write to storage?

Comment: how can I check and set it ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>